# ?. in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining

Is **?.** a valid operator in Typescript or Javascript?

I have seen code like below:

```
const var1 = obj1?.innerObj1?.somePropVal;
```

When I try this in the chrome console, I get an **error** if obj1 is undefined. Not sure whether this kind of code would work.

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: optional chaining (?.) is valid in both TypeScript and relatively recently also vanilla JS. The above code should work in chrome if you're using a somewhat up to date chrome

Comment: What do you mean with _"obj1 is undefined"_? I get an error when obj1 is not defined but I don't get an error when it's undefined. `undefined` and "not defined" are two different things in JavaScript. You can't use optional chaining to catch `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Are you talking about ternary operator ( ? : ) ?

Comment: @itiDi: OP is clearly not talking about that. `?.` is mentioned in the title, in the text and in the code example. It's highly unlikely that they mistyped 3 times and didn't notice. Also if you replace `?.` with `?:` in the sample, it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @itiDi I was talking about the optional chaining operator. I got the required explanation from other comments. Thank you.

Comment: @NickParsons I was able to read up on "optional chaining" and understand. Thanks a ton for helping with the term. That was the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const var1 = obj1?.innerObj1?.somePropVal;
```

is the same as:

```
const var1 = obj1 && obj1.innerObj1 ? obj1.innerObj1.somePropVal : undefined;
```